# Level Editor for Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

Do you know a level editor compatible with Sprite Kit for iOS?

I would need a software similar to [Cocos Builder](http://cocosbuilder.com) that is good but as far as I know it is not compatible with Sprite Kit.

Thank you.

Comment: I've searching this a month ago, but couldn't find anything

Comment: It's the same for me. I read that [SpriteBuilder](http://www.spritebuilder.com) (the evolution of CocosBuilder) could eventually support Sprite Kit but right now it does not look so.

Comment: There's at least one design tool for Sprite Kit in development, maybe two. That's all I have at this point, I'll let you know when I know more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a list. In alphabetical order, as of July 5th, 2015:

**Available:**

- [Level Helper 2](http://www.gamedevhelper.com) apparently supports Sprite Kit ([link to docs](http://www.gamedevhelper.com/apps/SpriteHelper/documentation/api/spritekit/index.html))
- [Sprite Kit Designer](http://www.spritekitdesigner.com) is designed specifically for Sprite Kit but has not been updated since April 2014 (possibly discontinued?)
- Xcode has a [Sprite Kit Scene Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014509-SW13) built-in (Scene Editor)

**Not (yet) available**

- [SpriteBuilder](http://www.spritebuilder.com) v1.1 beta had experimental support for Sprite Kit (w/o physics) but this feature was dropped.

If you know a Sprite Kit (or compatible) visual design tool that's not listed here please add it as a comment. I will update the list infrequently.

Comment: Do you know if SpriteBuilder for SpriteKit will also support Android via Apportable?

Comment: I didn't know Sprite Kit was "Apportable".  And I see we're using Apportable as an adjective now, eh? :-)

Comment: SpriteBuilder and Apportable dropped support for Sprite Kit as they have a compelling counter-offer to Sprite Kit / Xcode Playgrounds with cocos2d-swift and SpriteBuilder.

Comment: SpriteKit Designer sounded promising but was barely usable.

Comment: Oh my god there is a tool named sprite kit designer! I will check this right now! We are ready to make some games bigger but it's hard to do that with all-code by sprite kit. Thanks so much for your list! You save many days for me.

Comment: i would stay far away from any design tool that generates code rather than using a data file and a reader, so check that first

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but Xcode 6 which is in beta right now, has a level editor for SpriteKit built in. I'm having a hard time find a good tutorial on it, but its worth checking out. And if anyone finds a good tutorial on this, for a beginner like me, I'd love to know about it.

Comment: How about your learning? Is it easy and useful for build some games bigger? I had been working with spritekit for several months and making some games so small in all-code. But I want to make same games bigger and thinking  about to use spritebuilder instead of spritekit