# Looking For A Level Editor (SpriteKit)

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm making a game in SpriteKit with the 'world' being bigger than the actual screen size. I am know looking for a level editor for this game so that I don't have to give every sprite specific coordinates for the whole world. If anyone knows of any level editors that would fit my needs or if you have any advice on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Level Editor for Sprite Kit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548298/level-editor-for-sprite-kit)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org) (free) with this [library](https://github.com/slycrel/JSTileMap) (also free).